# How to achieve waterfall collection view in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, waterfall

**GOAL:** To achieve a waterfall collection view in xamarin forms.

**Tried:** I've achieved this in android using a custom renderer (staggered layout). Unfortunately, ios didn't provide a layout like this.

Referred this link
https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/master/ios9/CollectionView

But don't know to implement it in xamarin forms.Please help me for this.

Comment: For Android , we can implement it by using Custom Renderer (You could check this similar issue and I had posted the solution  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60718289/xamarin-forms-collectionview-custom-layout-design/60732899#60732899) . In iOS , because the UICollectionView in native iOS doesn't have such a property or API , so we need to implement it manually (re-calculate the size of each item and set the offset) . Which you could refer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/customizing_collection_view_layouts?language=objc .

Comment: You can follow the github thread https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6554 .